# Combine multiple applications into one

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, architecture

Imagine we have several independent apps on react/webpack/redux/etc. We need to create a new app which combines all of this apps in one.

**Example:**

We have the main app which renders header of secondary apps titles. When we click on each item we are loading the current secondary app with stylesheets and codebase.

How we can realize this with webpack? Or some another suggestion

Comment: Have you tried defining multiple entry points?

Comment: @Adam, yeah, something like that. But each application is developed in different repositories. I need some architecture solutions which can combine all apps